# Bluemix cloudant: Sudden errors being thrown by service

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

We are using Node.js module nano to interact with Cloudant instance on Bluemix. Suddenly today we have started getting the below errors while getting data from a view in a Cloudant instance. Any clue what might be wrong?

```
 [{couch_os_process,prompt,3,[{file,"src/couch_os_process.erl"},{line,65}]},
  {couch_query_servers,'-map_docs/2-fun-1-',2,
                       [{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,243}]},
  {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},
  {couch_query_servers,map_docs,2,
                       [{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,239}]},
  {couch_view_updater,view_compute,2,
                      [{file,"src/couch_view_updater.erl"},{line,256}]},
  {couch_view_updater,do_map,2,
                      [{file,"src/couch_view_updater.erl"},{line,161}]},
  {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1261}]},
  {couch_view_updater,do_maps,4,
                      [{file,"src/couch_view_updater.erl"},{line,153}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the indexer is crashing trying to index a particular document. Probably you made a change to your documents, likely the ingestion of a larger document. One indication that it is a 'recent' change to a document causing the crash is to query the view with *stale=ok*. This will request a response from the last built version of the index (with the last correct version of the document). If this returns correctly it means that the issue is caused by a recent change attempting to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an intermittent issue due to a login and application management issue in the US-South region. You can track Platform and Service issues at the [Bluemix Status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status). If the system status is okay and you still get these errors, open a [Bluemix Support  ticket](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem with one of the Map Reduce views you have defined on the design document that contains the view you are accessing.